# Redux state return empty arrays inside Formik FieldArray component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, formik

I'm currently migrating my app store to Redux, using react-redux and redux-toolkit. I've encountered an issue where the store behaves correctly when accessed outside the FieldArray component. However, when I try to access it within the FieldArray component, the store appears to be empty, returning empty arrays instead of the expected state.

This has left me quite confused and unsure of the cause.

```
const Empleados = ({ fieldName, formikProps, isFormEditable = true, ...restProps }) => {
    const { roles, empleados } = useSelector(state => state);
    const [empleadosListFormatted, setEmpleadosListFormatted] = useState([]);
    const [empleadosListFormattedLabelValue, setEmpleadosListFormattedLabelValue] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const empleadosListFormatted = empleados.map(empleado => {
            const rol = roles.find(rol => rol.id === empleado.rolId)?.nombre;
            return {
                ...empleado,
                nombre: `${empleado.nombre} ${empleado.apellido} (${rol})`
            }
        });

        const empleadosListFormattedLabelValue = empleadosListFormatted.map(empleado => {
            return {
                label: empleado.nombre,
                value: empleado.id,
            }
        });

        setEmpleadosListFormatted(empleadosListFormatted);
        setEmpleadosListFormattedLabelValue(empleadosListFormattedLabelValue);
    }, [empleados, roles]);

    const handleChangeEmpleado = (empleadoId, arrayHelper) => {
        if (empleadoId) {
            let current = empleados.find(e => e.id == empleadoId);
            arrayHelper.push({
                empleadoId: current.id,
                rolId: current.rolId
            });
        }
    }
    return <Card className="h-100" {...restProps}>
        <Card.Header>
            Empleados
        </Card.Header>
        <Card.Body>
            <div>{empleados.length}</div>
            <FieldArray
                name={fieldName}
                render={({ form, arrayHelpers }) => {
                    const empleadosFormikValues = form.values[fieldName];
                    console.log(empleados.length)
                    return <>
                        <div>{empleados.length}</div>
                        <UltimateSelectReactIdValue
                            label="Empleados con Rol"
                            options={empleadosListFormattedLabelValue}
                            onChange={(e) => handleChangeEmpleado(e, arrayHelpers)}
                            isDisabled={!isFormEditable}
                        />
                        <ol className="list-group list-group-numbered list-group-flush">
                            {empleados.length > 0 && roles.length > 0 && empleadosFormikValues.map((empleadoSelected, index) => {
                                const empleado = empleados.find(e => e.id === empleadoSelected.empleadoId);
                                const rol = roles.find(r => r.id === empleadoSelected.rolId);

                                return <li key={index} className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                    <span>{empleado.nombre} {rol.nombre}</span>
                                    {isFormEditable && <DeleteButton onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)} />}
                                </li>
                            }
                            )}
                            {empleadosFormikValues.length === 0 && <Alert variant="warning">No hay <b>Empleados</b> seleccionados.</Alert>}
                        </ol>
                        <BasicErrorFormik
                            touched={true}
                            error={form.errors[fieldName]}
                        />
                    </>
                }
                }
            />
        </Card.Body>
    </Card >
}
```

I already checked that the state is updating in the first "console.log" outside the component but the "console.log" inside FieldArray is empty.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqNoP.png)

That's the redux state when the component page is reloaded. You can see that we have 2 different number above "Empleados con Rol".

1. 199 (is counting the length of "empleados" array)
2. 0 (is counting the length of "empleados" array inside "FieldArray" component)

Comment: Could you please post some pics of *Redux DevTools* to get to know clearly about the issue you are facing?